# Использование realloc

Tags: c, указатели, realloc

Как правильно использовать realloc из malloc.h?
Есть код:

```
struct myStruct
{
    int count;
};

void func1(struct myStruct **ptr)
{
    if (*ptr!=NULL)
    {
        *ptr=realloc(*ptr,sizeof(struct myStruct)*10);
        ptr[2]->count=10;
    }
    else
        *ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));

}

int main()
{
    struct myStruct *ptr=NULL;
    func1(&ptr);
    func1(&ptr);
}
```

при выполнении

```
ptr[2]->count=10
```

происходит segmentation fault.
Смотрел адреса *ptr до и после realloc (они не изменились,вероятно изменились размеры выделенной области).
При изменении:

```
void func1()
{
    struct myStruct *new_ptr=NULL;
    if (*ptr!=NULL)
    {
        new_ptr=realloc(*ptr,sizeof(struct myStruct)*10);
        *ptr=new_ptr;
        ptr[2]->count=10;
    }
    else
        *ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));

}
```

все работает нормально.Как работает функция realloc?

Comment: `realloc` изменяет объём уже выделенного блока памяти. То есть сначала надо выделить память с помощью malloc или подобной функции.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev прощу прощения, забыл указать, но память выделяется и для *ptr!=NULL выполняется realloc

Comment: В вашем примере это не так.

Comment: *"Смотрел адреса *head до и после realloc"* - в приведенном коде нет никакого `head`. `ptr` указывает на массив из всего одного указателя, так что в `ptr[2]` будет выход за пределы массива. Присваивания `*ptr=` являются невалидными.  `realloc` в С++ правильно не использовать, как и сырые указатели. А вообще вам стоит определиться, для какого языка этот вопрос.

Comment: @VTT `ptr[2]` используется после realloc, где выделяется 10 элементов массива и почему тогда выхода не будет за границу, это не так?

Comment: `ptr` в `func1` и до, и после выделения памяти (успешного или неуспешного) продолжнает указывать не переменную `ptr`, которая объявлена в `main` Изменённый вариант по-прежнему неработоспособен.

Comment: Вы в func1 передаёте `ptr` - указатель на указатель на `struct myStruct`.  Потом Вы пишете - `ptr[2]->count = 10;`, то есть говорите компилятору, что у вас это массив так-то, и в нём аж целых указателя, и мол по второму указателю лежит структура, в поле которой `count` Вы хотите записать 10. Компилятор генерирует всё как Вы его попросили. А потом Вы в функции `main` отдаёте как параметр функции func1 не массив указателей, а указатель на указатель.

Comment: Во-первых, `realloc` объявлен в `<stdlib.h>`. В C нет никакого `<malloc.h>`. Во-вторых, оба варианта одинаково неработоспособны. Должно быть действительно `(*ptr)[2].count=10;`, как правильно написал elo. Ваше "все работает нормально" - это выдумка. В-третьих, откуда во втором варианте вообще взялось `ptr`???

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте заменить строку

```
ptr[2]->count=10;
```

на

```
(*ptr)[2].count=10;
```

Comment: segmentation fault

Comment: @SHAPs: Вы выдумываете. Никакого segmentation fault в таком варианте не будет.

Comment: Объясняем десятый раз: **ptr** это ссылка на массив или вектор массивов. `ptr[2]` - указывает на третий массив, а `(*ptr)` - на первый по ссылке. Чтобы поменять элемент в каком-то массиве, нужно сначала этот массив выбрать.